# Nginx Proxy URLs

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am trying to proxy_pass a dynamic location in nginx.

I have two servers with 1 acting as the main website and the other acting as a search service.

Whilst I can successfully pass the search page and results through to the main server - because the links within the results are relative to the search service - when clicking on the result I am redirected to the second server.

Essentially what I am trying to do is create a dynamic location with the proxy_pass value also being dynamic, too. Hopefully this will allow be to proxy the search service results, too.

As an example I require something like the below. The dynamic values would be the latter 3 location, id and listing elements.

```
location /property/location/id/listing {
       proxy_pass sub2.website.com/property/location/id/listing
}
```

Whilst I have created and suggested the location value - this actually doesn't exist on the 'main website' server by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
location /property/ {
       proxy_pass sub2.website.com/property/
}
```

as you want location, id, listing to be dynamic